# What should a gazetter list include?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract locations from hotel reviews , by locations I mean hotel names , cities , neighbourhoods , POIs and countries . I am using a gazetter list with 165,000 entities[ this list doesn't have hotel names ] marked as location . 
I have sloppygazette turned on but this gazette isn't helping much . I am confused about what should include I  in the gazetter list.

PS : I am a novice as far as NLP is concerned , so little help about which features to be used is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is new more detailed documentation about the NER functionality here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

The rules format is one rule per line:

`Los Angeles  CITY    LOCATION,MISC   1.0`

`Great Wall Of China  LANDMARK    LOCATION,MISC   1.0`

Some of the functionality is only available if you use the latest code from GitHub, but a lot is available in Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1

In short the NER annotator runs these steps:

1. statistical NER models
2. rules for numeric sequences and SUTime (for times and dates)
3. rules for fine grained NER (CITY, STATE_OR_PROVINCE, COUNTRY, etc...)
4. additional rules specified by user (this is new and not currently available in 3.9.1)
5. build entity mentions (identify that tokens "Los" and "Angeles" should be the entity "Los Angeles)

You can either download the code from GitHub and build the latest version, or you can just add your custom rules to the `ner.fine.regexner` annotator as described in the link above.

Comment: can you give me an example of what gazetteer should contain if i want to tag locations in my text. I am talking about proper nouns here like Times Square or Great wall of china .

Comment: The rule format would be the same as the example rule for Los Angeles in the answer.  A rule file has one rule per line.

Comment: I added an example for Great Wall Of China...the second column is what tag to apply.  You can set that to whatever you want.

Comment: If you wanted it to be LOCATION though, you should remove LOCATION from the third column, which is the list of named entity tags that can be overwritten by the rule.

Comment: I meant what kind of entities should I include if I want to tag locations , Suppose I don't have great wall of china in my training data and want to tag it as location in the test data , but including it in the gazetter has no effect . It still isn't marked as location.